# getting the next row of a data frame with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to pull the next row value from a data frame by setting a condition it will meet.

I got this data frame: 

in:

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_path)
df['Stock Name'] = stock_symbol
print(df.head())
df = df.reset_index()`

out:

```
Date   Open    High      Low     ...      Adj Close   Volume  Stock Name                                     ...

1996-12-12  1.81250  1.8125  1.68750     ...       0.743409  1984400        CALM
1996-12-13  1.71875  1.8125  1.65625     ...       0.777510   996800        CALM
1996-12-16  1.81250  1.8125  1.71875     ...       0.750229   122000        CALM
1996-12-17  1.75000  1.8125  1.75000     ...       0.774094   239200        CALM
1996-12-18  1.81250  1.8125  1.75000     ...       0.791151   216400        CALM
```

I got this code now:

in:

`data_from_yahoo=df.loc[df['Date'] == ddate]
data_from_yahoo_next_day=df.loc[df['Date'] == ddate].shift(1)
print(data_from_yahoo)
print(data_from_yahoo_next_day)`

out:

```
Date       Open  High     ...      Adj Close  Volume  Stock Name
5610 2019-04-01  46.700001  47.0     ...      42.987827  846900        CALM
Date  Open  High  Low  Close  Adj Close  Volume Stock Name
5610  NaT   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN
```

now I want to get the row that is after the "data_from_yahoo" row, in this case, it would be row 5611.
the problem is in the `data_from_yahoo_next_day=df.loc[df['Date'] == ddate].shift(1)` i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
data_from_yahoo_next_day = df[df['Date'].shift(1) == ddate]
```